# affect a specific workbook instead of all workbooks opened

Tags: excel, vba

How do you create an Excel VBA macro for a single specific workbook?

This is my VBA code. I would like it to affect a specific workbook instead of all workbooks opened on the computer. Is there a way I can specify the workbook name?

```
Sub deja_vu()
Dim wb As Workbook
Set wb = ThisWorkbook
wb.Save
Application.OnTime Now + TimeValue("00:00:10"), "deja_vu"
End Sub
```

Comment: Your code currently affects (only) ThisWorkbook which is the workbook where your code is stored. If you want to save a different workbook, change the 3rd line and set it to that workbook (eg `Set wb = Workbooks("myWorkbook.xlsx")`)

Comment: Not sure if saving a workbook every 10 seconds is such a good idea. Also I don't see how this would ever affect any other workbook than the one the code is written in. That code will *never* affect *all workbooks* as you say in your title. So this makes your question very unclear actually.